# Monitor for multimedia (22")

Tags: usb, monitors, hdmi

I'm searching for a new monitor, I currently own (for more or less 1 years) a [Dell UltraSharp 24"](http://www1.euro.dell.com/content/products/productdetails.aspx/dell-u2414h?c=uk&l=en&s=dhs&cs=ukdhs1) (U2414H) which is a very good monitor but I feel uncomfortable with it (24 inches is too big for me and due to the conception of the screen it appear also too close from me) and would like to switch with a 22" monitor.

**Requirement :**

- ~22 inches
- Full HD resolution (1920x1080)
- HDMI and at least 3 USB port (audio I/O is a plus)
- Available in Europe
- < 250€

Main usage of the monitor is for multimedia and programming, nothing fancy, I don't need internal speakers. I would like something like [ASUS VX229H](https://www.asus.com/us/Monitors/VX229H/) but it don't have any USB ports neither audio I/O.

Comment: I don't know too much about monitors so I don't know what I can add

Comment: Your USB and audio I/O usually comes from the backplate of your PC, rather than from the monitor.

Comment: My current Dell UltraSharp have 4 USB ports and one jack port : http://multimonitorcomputer.com/solved/images/dell-U2414H-displayport.jpg, It's very helpfull for me because my PC tower at least 1 meter from my monitor.

Comment: Sure, but adding I/O like that means you have a lot fewer monitors to choose from, and adds expense to the product. I'd suggest a USB hub instead; see my answer below.

Comment: I don't care about expense if it fits under my budget limit or a little more, USB hub are one option but they are already a lots of stuff on my desk all the time, I would prefer to not add something else, thanks anyway.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Alternatively, you could have the [**Dell UltraSharp U2212HM 21.5"**](http://www.dell.com/ed/business/p/dell-u2212h/pd) monitor. Very similar to your current monitor, but in 21.5" size.

- 21.5"
- 1920x1080 Full HD
- 4 USB ports
- HDMI
- Available, like most/all Dell monitors, in Europe
- I'm finding prices between 135€ and 160€; prices will vary depending on which retailer you pick.

As you've probably already worked out, Dell are one of the best for monitors. This is a pretty solid bet - I've not used one myself, but I know a couple of people who use either this monitor or a close relative and have been very satisfied with it.

Comment: No HDMI for this one, only VGA and DVI. No mentions of HDMI anywhere in the specs and from one reviews on amazon : "1. First, the small thing. There's no HDMI port, but instead a DisplayPort port." https://www.amazon.com/Dell-PF48H-21-5-Inch-Discontinued-Manufacturer/dp/B005OHPW1Q

Comment: I'm sure the spec said HDMI when I saw it...

Answer (score 1):

I'll recommend a close relative to the monitor I use: the **[AOC Vesa I2269VWM 21.5"](https://www.amazon.co.uk/dp/B00BDBVCCK)**.

- 21.5" is pretty close to your 22" requirement. There are also 23" and 27" options, though I imagine you'd rather not go for those.
- 1920x1080 full HD
- No USB ports. If you want USB ports on your desk rather than having to dig for the PC I/O plate every time, I recommend you get a USB hub rather than looking for a monitor with integrated USB ports - the majority of monitors will come without them, and having them will make a monitor more expensive.
- 2 (i.e. stereo) loudspeakers
- AOC do sell in Europe; I haven't confirmed that *this model* is available in Europe, but it's certainly available in the UK.
- £104.16 / 121,58€ (based on UK price and current exchange rates; EUR figure subject to change)

AOC are generally pretty reliable; my AOC has been going for a year so far, and the AOC monitors my workplace uses have been going for 8-ish years.